# JSON value truncated in server

Tags: json, node.js, axios, windows-server-2012, node-rest-client

```
var authOptions = {
method: 'POST',
url: url,
data: options.data,
headers: options.headers,
json: true  };

return axios(authOptions)
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);

})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

This is my code snippet. I am trying to make a request to an URL which works fine in my local system. But, when I am running this code inside a windows-server, the JSON returned is incomplete and truncated. It throws an error, unexpected end of JSON. I have tried using the node-rest-client and request as well, but the error persists. any insights into this issue ?

TIA

Comment: Have you been able to log the data at all? I mean sometimes the `data` is completely empty or not json (like HTML from IIS complaining about something). Try setting `json: false` and see what the data contains?

Comment: I am able to log the data sucessfully in both server and client. In server alone, JSON is truncated.

Comment: On the server, you're just running a node process and requesting that data as a user running on the server? No proxy/IIS between you and the node process?

Comment: Yes. Just running the node server. No proxy/IIS . Is that a problem?

Comment: No that's good because then its not some obscure IIS configuration :) How big is the payload? Maybe try using the connection: "keep-alive" header to be sure the server doesn't close the conn early? Also, I think its very unlikely, but if the Content-Length is set wrong things can behave wierdly.

Comment: Payload is 19kb.Thanks for prompt reply. Will try the keep-alive header :).

Comment: Still no luck. I tried keep-alive as well. I tried as per this one https://medium.com/@ccnokes/one-con-i-discovered-about-axios-recently-is-that-it-doesnt-have-the-best-default-configuration-e6e3a8cba6fa

Comment: Maybe try going around axios? Make the request with superagent or something? If it works then, then the problem is axios for sure.

Comment: I have used node-rest-client and request but not superagent. Will give it a try..

Comment: another factor could be browser; maybe try another browser if it is IE?

Comment: There is no browser involved. Just checking in the command prompt.

Comment: Could also be related to your body parser. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser has a limit of 100kb by default.

Comment: But this is for req.body only right ? //Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property.

//

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a problem with the nodejs code. Windows network settings have put some restrictions on size while receiving the data. Once those restrctions are removed, it works like charm.

Comment: Hi - I am facing the same error - while using axios to post a large JSON to a Spring-boot server. Its not on Windows machine. But would like to know what settings were changed here. Could you please let me know?

Comment: You need to increase the size limit of JSON that can be processed by Nodejs

Comment: Thanks @Nigilan. Can you please let us how to increase the size limit?